# Can a static member variable call non-static member functions?

Tags: c++

I saw the following code:
http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton/cpp/1

```
class GlobalClass
{
private:
    int m_value;
    static GlobalClass *s_instance;
    GlobalClass(int v = 0)
    {
        m_value = v;
    }
public:
    int get_value()
    {
        return m_value;
    }
    void set_value(int v)
    {
        m_value = v;
    }
    static GlobalClass *instance()
    {
        if (!s_instance)
            s_instance = new GlobalClass;
        return s_instance;
    }
};

GlobalClass *GlobalClass::s_instance = 0;

void foo(void)
{
    GlobalClass::instance()->set_value(1); // static variable calls non-static functions
    cout << "foo: global_ptr is " << GlobalClass::instance()->get_value() << '\n';
}
```

As I know (please correct me if I am wrong here),

1. Static functions can only access(write/read) static member variables
2. Non-Static functions can access(write/read) static member variables

Based on above sample, it seems that a static variable can access non-static functions.
Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Variables don't call anything**

(This doesn't really address the sample code, but it corrects a misconception in the two "rules" listed beneath the code)

A static member function is a member, and can access all public, protected, and private members of its class, both static and instance.

However, static member functions have no `this` pointer, so to access an instance member, the instance needs to be specified.

Comment: A static member function cannot access non-static member variable.

Comment: @q0987: Yes it can.  I can give you an example, but I'd really prefer that you stop and think about my answer first.  Learning to think about software is a very important part of learning to program.

Comment: I agree with q0987: static member functions can use only static data members. What you are showing in your example Ben Voigt, is that the INSTANCE can access the non static data member.

Answer (score 4):

> it seems that a static variable can access non-static functions.

the code you have doesn't do quite what you just said.

To understand what it's doing, lets back up a bit and talk about what `class` really means.  classes define new types.  another type is `int`.  an instance of an int can be located in a functions local variables or parameters, it can be stored on the heap by calling `new int`, it can be global by declaring one at the file scope.  none of them know or care where they are stored, but they are all instances of the type `int`.

When you make an instance of a `class`, you are creating the space used and the behaviors on the instance of that class, and those behaviors apply to every instance equally.

classes can also do something that isn't part of defining the data and behaviors of its instances, and those are the static members of the class.

Since these concepts are fundamentally separate, they don't really interfere with each other.  in fact, you could have one of the static members of the class refer to an instance of the class, and that's exactly what this example of the singleton pattern does.

So what's actually happening, from the very beginning is you are creating an instance of the class, using `new GlobalClass`, and then keeping the pointer someplace.  It happens that the pointer is being saved as a static member of the same class that defines the type of the instance you just created.

then `GlobalClass` provides a mechanism to use that instance.  when you invoke `GlobalClass::instance()`, it reads a static class variable, which is allowed.  the variable holds a pointer, which when dereferenced (via `->`) results in the one object we created earlier, and that object, since it is an instance of GlobalClass, is now allowed to access an instance variable.

Comment: Hello TokenMacGuy, GlobalClass::instance() returns s_instance which is a static member variable. So I assume that this function returns a static member variable. Am I correct? -- thank you

Comment: @q0987 - yes, that's correct.  Static methods can't access non-static methods, but an instance - static or otherwise - can access both.

Comment: @Phil, this is the point that I feel confused. Since the returned instance is a static variable. How can this static variable calls a non-static member function set_value and changes non-static member variable m_value? In other words, how does a static variable determines which 'this' to use? -- thank you

Comment: Once again, the variable isn't calling anything.  The `foo` function is calling non-static member functions, which needs an instance.  There is an instance, it came from `GlobalClass::instance()`.  Furthermore, `GlobalClass::instance()` doesn't return `s_instance`, it returns a copy of it (a copy of a pointer is another pointer to the same address).

Comment: @q0987 - The modifier `static` on the method `instance()` means that you don't need an instance of `GlobalClass` to invoke it.  The modifier `static` on `s_instance` means there is just 1 of it, and all instances share it.  `static` here describes how the class uses the it.  But at the end of the day, it's still an instance of the class itself.  And instances can access static and non-static methods.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy, @Phil: Instances don't access things.  Functions access things.  If you try to explain things in terms of the instance on which the non-static member function is called, you will find it absolutely impossible to explain access modifiers (`public`/`protected`/`private`).

Answer (score 3):

`instance`, as its name suggests, returns a pointer to an instance.  It also uses a static instance pointer field, `s_instance`.  The fact that this is static means that there is only one `s_instance` field per class.  Once you get that instance pointer (from `instance`), you can use it like any other instance pointer.  The facts that you got it via a static method, and that the method uses a static field, are irrelevant.

The static method itself is valid; it doesn't use `this` implicitly or explicitly.

Comment: More succinct than I could manage.  I think he's also confused that `s_instance` itself is static, not just the method by which he gets the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The technical issues have already been posted in other answers, I will just add an example trying to help with the confusion. Imagine that you create a class Human to represent a human being, it can have properties like the color of the eyes, the name and such... and methods that define the actions like walk, jump... those properties and methods are particular to each *instance* of Human: a particular human might have blue eyes, and you can ask her to talk.

In a different level, there might be properties or actions that are not particular to the *instance* but rather to the whole class of Humans, like who is the tallest or the eldest human. Those are declared *static* as belonging to the whole set of humans, rather than to each individual.

Now, once you obtain an individual from the class, say the tallest, that individual is a Human, and as such you can request any property you want, or you can request any action you need: `Human::get_tallest().get_something_from_cupboard()` will request the tallest (`get_tallest()`) Human in the set (class action) and then request that particular individual to perform an action for you (`get_something_from_cupboard()`) which is an action performed by a particular *instance*.